# Scrapy errors with "view" and OAI-PMH

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, oai

I'm using scrapy to crawl over [this XML data](http://fukushima.archive-disasters.jp/infolib/oai_repository/repository?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=ndlkn) from an archive, which uses the [OAI-PMH framework](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/openarchivesprotocol.html). I am not extremely familiar with exactly how OAI-PMH could affect Scrapy, but there seems to be a problem when I use the following command:

```
scrapy view http://fukushima.archive-disasters.jp/infolib/oai_repository/repository?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=ndlkn
```

Instead of the website opening in my browser, a Notepad file opens up with the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd"> <responseDate>
    2013-12-30T00:11:45Z</responseDate>
    <request>http://fukushima.archive-disasters.jp/infolib/oai_repository/repository</request>
    <error code="badArgument">It is an inaccurate parameter.</error>
```

And the following comes up on the command line:

```
[default] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
'metadataPrefix' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The only time `metadataPrefix` shows up in the XML is in the 3rd line:

```
<request metadataPrefix="ndlkn" verb="ListRecords">
```

Is there any way I can use this website with Scrapy's "view" command?

Also, I'm also having trouble accessing the XML data itself through the scrapy shell. In the previous version of scrapy, after using `remove_namespaces()` I could access all the records on the page using `sel.xpath('//record')`, but now that generates `[]` and I'm having trouble figuring out the correct xpath needed.

Here's how the following commands look:

```
scrapy shell http://fukushima.archive-disasters.jp/infolib/oai_repository/repository?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=ndlkn
```

Typical scrapy output, then:

```
    >>> sel.remove_namespaces()
    >>> sel.xpath('//record')
    []
    >>> sel.xpath('//OAI-PMH')
    [<Selector xpath='//OAI-PMH' data=u'<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.'>]
    >>> sel.xpath('//OAI-PMH/request')
    [<Selector xpath='//OAI-PMH/request' data=u'<request xmlns="http://www.openarchives.'>]
    >>> sel.xpath('//OAI-PMH/ListRecords')
    []
```

What xpaths do I need to use?

Sorry for the long question. I'm just worried that the two issues are linked and that OAI-PMH is causing problems here. Please let me know if I should break this up or any other ways I can make it more clear.

EDIT: I feel super dumb, but I realized the problem. Because there's an `&` in the URL, it needs to be in quotes or escaped after calling `scrapy view` or `scrapy shell`. That fixes both of my issues! Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it so that this question appears resolved.

Comment: Yeah, I tried last night, but because my reputation is under 10 I had to wait 8 hours or something. So now it's up, but I can't accept it until tomorrow, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized my mistake.  Because there's an `&` in the URL, it needs to be in quotes or escaped after `scrapy view` or `scrapy shell`. That fixes both of my issues! Hope this helps anyone in the future.